# How to get data from vuex state into local data for manipulation

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I'm having trouble understanding how to interact with my local state from my vuex state. I have an array with multiple items inside of it that is stored in vuex state. I'm trying to get that data from my vuex state into my components local state. I have no problems fetching the data with a getter and computed property but I cannot get the same data from the computed property into local state to manipulate it. My end goal is to build pagination on this component.

I can get the data using a getters and computed properties. I feel like I should be using a lifecycle hook somewhere.

### Retrieving Data

### App.vue:

I'm attempting to pull the data before any components load. This seems to have no effect versus having a created lifecycle hook on the component itself.

```
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {
      //
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$store.dispatch("retrieveSnippets");
  }
};
```

### State:

This is a module `store/modules/snippets.js`

```
const state = {
   snippets: []
}

const mutations = {
SET_SNIPPETS(state, payload) {
    state.snippets = payload;
  },
}

const actions = {
retrieveSnippets(context) {
    const userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    db.collection("projects")
      .where("person", "==", userId)
      .orderBy("title", "desc")
      .onSnapshot(snap => {
        let tempSnippets = [];
        snap.forEach(doc => {
          tempSnippets.push({
            id: doc.id,
            title: doc.data().title,
            description: doc.data().description,
            code: doc.data().code,
            person: doc.data().person
          });
        });
        context.commit("SET_SNIPPETS", tempSnippets);
      });
  }
}

const getters = {
  getCurrentSnippet(state) {
    return state.snippet;
},
```

### Inside Component

```
data() {
    return {
      visibleSnippets: [],
   }
}
computed: {
stateSnippets() {
      return this.$store.getters.allSnippets;
    }
}
```

### HTML:

you can see that i'm looping through the array that is returned by stateSnippets in my html because the computed property is bound. If i remove this and try to loop through my local state, the computed property doesn't work anymore.

```
<v-flex xs4 md4 lg4>
  <v-card v-for="snippet in stateSnippets" :key="snippet.id">
    <v-card-title v-on:click="snippetDetail(snippet)">{{ snippet.title }}</v-card-title>
  </v-card>
</v-flex>
```

My goal would be to get the array that is returned from `stateSnippets` into the local data property of `visibleSnippets`. This would allow me to build pagination and manipulate this potentially very long array into something shorter.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can get the state into your template in many ways, and all will be **reactive**.

## Directly In Template

```html
<div>{{$store.state.myValue}}</div>
<div v-html='$store.state.myValue'></div>
```

## Using computed

```html
<div>{{myValue}}</div>
```

```js
computed: {
  myValue() { return this.$store.state.myValue }
}
```

## Using the Vuex mapState helper

```html
<div>{{myValue}}</div>
```

```js
computed: {
  ...mapState(['myValue'])
}
```

You can also use `getters` instead of accessing the state directly.

The de-facto approach is to use mapGetters and mapState, and then access the Vuex data using the local component.

## Using Composition API

```html
<div>{{myValue}}</div>
```

```js
setup() {
 // You can also get state directly instead of relying on instance.
 const currentInstance = getCurrentInstance()
 const myValue = computed(()=>{
   // Access state directly or use getter
   return currentInstance.proxy.$store.state.myValue
 }) 

 // If not using Vue3 <script setup>
 return {
  myValue
 }
}
```

Comment: This works to get whatever is stored in my vuex state into the component template. However, what if I have arrayOne that has 10 items inside of it and I would only like to show the first 5 of those items in my component. I'd need to slice the array and output that into the template. Do I handle this manipulation in vuex or can I do this locally on the component? Maybe a better question is, can I store the vuex state data in my local components data also?

Comment: Add a computed that filters what you want.  You can base that computed off of another computed.  Or you can add this as a getter in Vuex if you reuse the logic, to keep things DRY.

Comment: You should only store your data in 1 place, BTW.  If only the component, or the components children need it, put it in `data`, otherwise put it in `Vuex store`.

Comment: Ahhhh that helps! I'm trying to store data in 2 places. Ok I'll give this a shot probably with a getter. Thank you!

Comment: Downvote: I know this is an older post, but please please please remove the example hat shows directly in template (the first one). Using v-html has security issues and in conjunction with un-sanitised API call data can get you in real trouble security wise. Also I'd never recommend doing this as computed properties are the way to go here (or maybe an init function and setting it in component data, but you won't have reactivity then).

Comment: @JeffreyvanderLem-Meesters There are NO security issues if you SANIZE your input, and that is outside of the scope of the question.  If you have issues with v-html, complain to vue team to remove it.

Comment: It's much simpler in composition API now: first `const store = useStore()` and then `computed(() => store.state.count)`. Source: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api.html#accessing-state-and-getters

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are getting how Flux/Vuex works completely wrong. Flux and its implementation in Vuex is one way flow. So your component gets data from store via [mapState](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#the-mapstate-helper) or [mapGetters](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#the-mapgetters-helper). This is one way so then you dispatch actions form within the component that in the end commit. Commits are the only way of modifying the store state. After store state has changed, your component will immediately react to its changes with latest data in the state.

Note: if you only want the first 5 elements you just need to slice the data from the store. You can do it in 2 different ways:

1 - Create a getter.

```
getters: {
    firstFiveSnipets: state => {
        return state.snipets.slice(0, 5);
    }
}
```

2 - Create a computed property from the mapState.

```
computed: {
    ...mapState(['allSnipets']),
    firstFiveSnipets() {
        return this.allSnipets.slice(0, 5);
    }
}
```

Comment: This helps, can you check my comment on @StevenSpungins answer?